# QuantLib OvernighIborBasisSwapRateHelper

Tags: quantlib

I am trying to use QuantLib OvernighIborBasisSwapRateHelper for some curve stripping. My Basis Swap is with settlement days as 2, and another 2-day payment lag, and 0 accrual day lag for both legs. While the interface of QL OvernighIborBasisSwapRateHelper only provides argument for settlement days but no option for payment lag. Am I missing it? or do we have someway to detour it?

Comment: You're right, the parameter is missing.  I suggest you open an issue on QuantLib's Github repository so it goes into the next release.